# how to create rails initializer for heroku config vars?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, actionmailer

I'm struggling with Heroku sending gmail with actionmailer in my Rails app.

I've got my gmail username and password correctly set as Heroku config vars, but I still get authentication errors. I finally discovered that I need to create an initializer but I'm having trouble hooking everything together. The following code brings up the correct username and password in the heroku logs, but with a NoMethodError. Not sure where to put the method to make it all work. I've tried putting it in my users_controller but that makes the whole thing crash.

I'm planning to add my S3 stuff to this initializer once I get this working.

my initializers/heroku.rb

```
GMAIL_CREDENTIALS = { :username => ENV['GMAIL_USERNAME'],
  :password => ENV['GMAIL_PASSWORD'] }
```

my mailers/user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "mygmailaddress", :gmail_credentials => GMAIL_CREDENTIALS

  def signup_confirmation(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Sign Up Confirmation"
  end
end
```

and create in my users_controller:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    UserMailer.signup_confirmation(@user).deliver
    sign_in @user
    flash[:success] = "Welcome to Plain Vanilla!"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

The error message in heroku logs:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 482ms
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:21:in `create'
NoMethodError (undefined method `encoding' for {:username=>"mygmailusername",
  :password=>"mypassword"}:Hash):
```

Thanks for any help!

Charlie

Comment: You should include the actual error you receive from this code.

Comment: can you paste your create action too, please

Comment: @stephenmurdoch -- added it. Sorry for not putting it there in the first place but a couple earlier questions of mine didn't get looked at much so I thought maybe I was posting too much code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally put my gmail credentials in an intializer called `mailer.rb`. It looks like this:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "mail.google.com",
  :user_name            => ENV['MY_GMAIL_USER_NAME'],
  :password             => ENV['MY_GMAIL_PASSWORD'],
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Where did you get the code you're using? I'd try dropping the :gmail_credentials line from your user_mailer and using an initializer that's more like mine. Don't forget to restart your app if you change these files.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Well, I'm trying to hide my username and password from my git repo. So I've got all that in my production.rb file except for username and password. I have those in heroku config but heroku compiles without those configs. I need to initialize heroku somehow and their docs are kinda useless, from a newbie point of view.

Comment: This technique does allow you to keep your password out of git. Heroku have a great article on how to use [config/env vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars). You simply type: `heroku config:add MY_GMAIL_USER_NAME=helloworld@gmail.com MY_GMAIL_PASSWORD=password123` and your credentials are now available as environment variables inside their system. Only someone with command line access to your app would be able to read them.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Finally had my "duh" moment. I had been thinking those two lines needed to be somewhere else. All is finally working.